# Window pops up when batch printing PDF with Ghostscript

Tags: windows, pdf, ghostscript

I'm using GS 9.15 to batch print some PDF's on a windows machine. This is the command I'm using:

```
gswin64 -dNoCancel=true -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -sDEVICE=ljet4d -sOutputFile=%printer%[printer path] "[pdf path]"
```

Although this works a window pops up during the print and then closes.

Any way to hide it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use gswin64c (command line version) instead of gswin64 (windowed version).

Comment: But there is still pop up console window. Is it possible to hide popup windows completely?